# Using Laravel 5.4 route in AngularJS $http service

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and AngularJS. I have this function :

```
$scope.allPosts = function() {
        $http.get("/posts")
            .then(function(){
            }, function(error){
            });
};
```

How can I avoid using hardcoded `"/posts"` and instead using a Laravel route there ?

Thank you.

Comment: you are using a bad approach, if you want the laravel routes you must create an endpoint and return the list of routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply share your routes variable on app as Json object and call them using a common function. but you should only share web app related routes.

`view::share('routes',json_encode($routeArray))`;

in the header file of app

```
var routes = {{$routes}}
```

Create functions  to access routes from routes.js

```
function getRoute(key) {
var results = fetchFromObject()
if(results === false){
    return f
}else if (typeof results === 'undefined') {
    return f
}else{
    return results
}
}

function fetchFromObject(obj, prop) {

if(typeof obj === 'undefined') {
    return false;
}

var _index = prop.indexOf('.')
if(_index > -1) {
    return fetchFromObject(obj[prop.substring(0, _index)], prop.substr(_index + 1));
}

return obj[prop];
}
```

now call in your app `getRoute('key')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) package to get Laravel's routes in your JS:

```js
$http.get(laroute.route('posts'));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I need another way without using any other libraries.

Comment: @dwix - what do you want? Magic? Laravel is a backend framework. It doesn't run on the frontend. If you want to be able to use its routes on the frontend, you need a way to get it there. That's what this library is for.